# missing files after moving symbolic links around

Tags: linux, centos

I had a directory with a symlink that was in `location A` and pointing to `location B`.

I recently moved `location A` to `location C` and `Location B` to `location D`.

even tho I moved the files the symlinks where still pointing to their original location, which might of caused an issue because now I can’t find the files I was pointing too.

I’m afraid they may have been deleted or lost in my user space, is there a way in Linux to search for them even if their aren’t visibly found?

Comment: You could use `find`. But from your description it sounds like you already know where the files are, and you could just update the symlinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your symlinks aren't going to work anymore as the original files they were pointing to are no longer in their original locations

You can locate them again wirth the `find` command and then create new symlinks to them in their current location. For future reference, it's better to create new symlinks immediately after moving the files in order to avoid this.